# Python Dunder method for printing all variables contained by a function? For custom debugging decorator

Tags: python-3.6

Is there a way to print all of a function's variables? I want to build a custom debugging decorator, and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I'm assuming there is some dunder method for this? So for a function:

```
def debugger(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__funcVariables__) #Some dunder method that Prints all variables contained in func
        return func
    return wrapper

@debugger
def my_func():
    x = 'foo'
    y = 'bar'
```

I would want 'foo' and 'bar' printed to the console from the decorator. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `function.__code__.co_varnames`, which is a tuple of the names of the functions arguments and local variables.  This is documented with the rest of the code introspection tools in the [documentation for the `inspect` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html)

```
def debugger(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(func.__code__.co_varnames) 
        return func
    return wrapper

@debugger
def my_func():
    x = 'foo'
    y = 'bar'
```